# F1-score evaluation in tensorflow custom training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

How should f1-score be evaluated during a custom training and evaluating loop in TensorFlow in a binary classification task?

I have checked some online sources. The solution using tfa simply does not work, some self-written f1score functions cannot integrate into the custom training loop. Specifically, in order to follow the same usage pattern as other evaluation metrics, such as keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy, keras.metrics.AUC, I think I should extend on the tf.keras.metrics.Metric class, but I am not capable of writing such an evaluation function myself.

```
# Get model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer to train the model.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Prepare the metrics.
train_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
val_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()


import time

epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    start_time = time.time()

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

        # Update training metric.
        train_acc_metric.update_state(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Log every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
            print("Seen so far: %d samples" % ((step + 1) * batch_size))

    # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
    train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
    print("Training acc over epoch: %.4f" % (float(train_acc),))

    # Reset training metrics at the end of each epoch
    train_acc_metric.reset_states()

    # Run a validation loop at the end of each epoch.
    for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in val_dataset:
        val_logits = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
        # Update val metrics
        val_acc_metric.update_state(y_batch_val, val_logits)
    val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
    val_acc_metric.reset_states()
    print("Validation acc: %.4f" % (float(val_acc),))
    print("Time taken: %.2fs" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Specifically, I wonder how I can calculate f1-score in exactly the same way as the train_acc_metric and val_acc_metric in the following code segment. (i.e. call update_state, result, reset_state at exactly the same location as train_acc_metric and val_acc_metric)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
f1 = 2*(tf.compat.v1.metrics.recall(labels, predictions) * tf.compat.v1.metrics.precision(labels, predictions)) / ( tf.compat.v1.metrics.recall(labels, predictions) + tf.compat.v1.metrics.precision(labels, predictions))
```

or you can try this one

```
def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

or this one

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
                 loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                 metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                          tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                          tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                          tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=nb_classes,
                                              average='macro',
                                              threshold=0.5))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am not familiar with TensorFlow yet. It seems that when I write the training/evaluation loop by myself, I cannot call compile method on the model. That is why I need to implement the "update_state()", "result()" and "reset_state" methods by myself, so that I can invoke these methods at appropriate locations inside of the custom training/evaluation loop. Besides, I am not sure but it seems that the F1Score class from the tfa package cannot directly handle the basic binary classification tasks.